# Why doesn't my Raycasting work in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

My raycasting dosen't seem to work when i assign it max distance, and works fine with infinite distance.

Player is moving forward, and it touches the object but still no debug message. DrawRay draws a ray how its supose to.

```
void CastForwardRay()
{
    int rayLength = 3;
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    Ray ray = new Ray(rayCastTransform.position, rayCastTransform.forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(rayCastTransform.position, rayCastTransform.forward * rayLength, Color.white);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, rayLength, playerLM))
    {
        if(hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Car")
        {
            print("hit a car");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. It could be not exist between ray, I mean, there is no object between origin of ray and end of ray
2. It should have PhysicsRaycaster in parent of hierarchy.

Comment: There is an object betwen, player is literaly touching the object, and the distance is set to 3. It just dosen't work when i set the max distance. I dont know what u mean with PhysicsRaycaster to be in parent.

Comment: I though, it was related 'PhysicsRaycaster' but your case, did you check that ray actually going to hit to specific object (gameObject)?

Comment: Yes like i said it does hit, just not when i limit the distance idk..

Comment: Are you in 2D or 3D?

Comment: im in 3D, still not fixed